# Changing the predefined axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, cad

I have a graphic which was taken from a CAD data and I opened it in MATLAB. The thing that I want to do is to rotate the figure 90 deg and to change the axes as in the figure.

[image]

I saved the figure in stl format and using the code in the following link I open it as a matlab figure.

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3642-cad2matdemo-m

Questions:

1. I don't have any function or m file to regenerate the figure. How can I rotate the axes in the figure?
2. How can I get the all points location in the figure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends entirely on the the format. You need to give us more than you do I am afraid.

Comment: I have a trajectory to follow in .stl format and I converted it to matlab file using the code in https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3642-cad2matdemo-m

Comment: Ok, try to put this in the question. Further, I do not want to follow a link to MATLAB file exchange just to know what you tries to do and so no one else want. This is why you get three votes to close.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a way to regenerate the figure data, but still have a MATLAB figure with the data inside it, you can retrieve them.

I first create a sample graphic object (a `patch`, as returned by the function you linked):

```
R = 3 ; nFaces = 5 ;
tt = linspace(0,2*pi,nFaces+1).' ; tt(end) = [] ;

[x,y] = pol2cart(tt,zeros(nFaces,1)+R) ;
hp = patch(x,y,'b') ;
axis equal
```

[image: pentagon]

---

Now, provided the figure is the active figure (click on the figure to give it focus if you want to be sure), you can query the data plotted inside.

First we need to get the handle of all the graphic objects displayed in the `axes` of the current figure:

```
% get handle of all graphic objects in the current axes
hlist = get(gca,'Children')

hlist = 
  Patch with properties:

    FaceColor: [0 0 1]
    FaceAlpha: 1
    EdgeColor: [0 0 0]
    LineStyle: '-'
        Faces: [1 2 3 4 5]
     Vertices: [5x2 double]
```

In my case there is only one object, so no ambiguity. If there was several handles returned, choose amongst the `patch` objects (play with each one and find out which is what).

Once the object you want to access is identified, is it easy to rotate:

```
% only one object in this case but if there was several in the list I
% would isolate the object I want to manipulate. 
hp = hlist(1) ;

% to rotate the graphic object "hp", around axis Z ([0 0 1]), by 90 degrees.
rotate( hp ,[0 0 1] , 90 )
```

[image: pentagon rotated]

or to retrieve the coordinates of the points:

```
% to get the points coordinates:
pc = get(hp,'Vertices')

pc =
   0.286474508437579   2.713525491562421                   0
  -2.566695040447882   0.640576474687264                   0
  -1.476881248439841  -2.713525491562421                   0
   2.049830265314998  -2.713525491562421                   0
   3.139644057323040   0.640576474687263                   0
```

Just be careful, the coordinates I retrieved, 5 points(lines) with `X`, `Y` and `Z` coordinates (columns) are the coordinates **after** the rotation. If you want the original coordinates you have to query them before you apply the rotation to the object.

---

More reading:

- The [`rotate`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate.html)
  command.
- The [`patch`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html)
  objects.